# how to deal with this kind of error

Tags: c#, ms-access

i received this kind of error:

> Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'acount no = no.,'

...everytime i withdraw or deposit something

```
string sql = default(string);
DataTable Log_in = new DataTable();

con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\anaabenoja\Documents\sample connection.accdb";
sql = "SELECT * FROM Acc_info where  account_no = " + lblaccno.Text + "";

cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = sql;
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
**da.Fill(Log_in);**
if (Log_in.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ....
```

Comment: the error gives you all information that we'd have, too, so start interpreting it.

Comment: Also, an unrelated issue, but you've got a typo in `Insuffiecient` (sic).

Answer (score 0):

The error message absolutely gives you what you need:

> Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'acount no = no.,'

If you look at your query, you'll find the mistake:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Acc_info where  account_no = " + lblaccno.Text + "";
```

You don't put the actual value of some `TextBox`'s input into the query, but the `Text`-value of the **label** (which holds the string `no.`).

So if you change the query as follows it should work (assuming you have a TextBox *txtaccno*):

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Acc_info WHERE account_no = " + txtaccno.Text;
```

---

Additionally keep in mind, that your code is horribly **prone to sql injection**. If a malicious user puts something like `0; DELETE FROM Acc_info;` into your TextBox, you'll have a problem...
To prevent these attacks you can use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[image]